# Redis sessions not persisting throughout different requests in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, express-session

I have 2 routes on the backend of my app.
The first one sets a session using redis and using a different route i try to retrieve the session that was saved prior. However, when trying to retrieve the session, i get a different one from the one i created.

this is how i create a session and assign a property to it:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
req.session.userId = 1
});
```

and this is how i try to retrieve it:

```
app.get("/cookie", (req, res) => {
res.json(req.session);
});
```

But when the `req.session` of the get request is logged, I get one without the property `userID`.
Even though, i am able to view the key and value of the session using the redis-client with the `keys` and `mget` command.

this is how the cookie and session is configured

```
app.use(
session({
  name: "cookie",
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  secret: "xxxxx",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10,
  },
})
);
```

and this is the `redisClient`:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
host: "localhost",
port: 6379,
});
```

How do I properly retrieve the session that i set on the post request? Am I using redis entirely wrong or am i just missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/session-management-in-nodejs-using-redis-as-session-store-64186112aa9